# How to output attributes of nodes of a Graph (NetworkX) into a DataFrame (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, graph-theory, networkx

I am working with networks as graph of the interaction between characters in Spanish theatre plays. Here a visualisation:

[image: Network of Bodas de Sangre, by Lorca]

I passed several attributes of the nodes (characters) as a dataframe to the network, so that I can use this values (for example the color of the nodes is set by the gender of the character). I want to calculate with NetworkX different values for each nodes (degree, centrality, betweenness...); then, I would like to output as a DataFrame both my attributes of the nodes and also the values calculated with NetworkX. I know I can ask for specific attributes of the nodes, like:

```
nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'degree')
```

And I could build a DataFrame using that, but I wonder if there is no a more elegant solution. I have tried also:

```
nx.to_dict_of_dicts(graph)
```

But this outputs only the edges and not the information about the nodes.

So, any help, please? Thanks!

Comment: With networkx >= 1.11 you have `nx.to_pandas_dataframe`

Comment: Hi! This creates the adjacency matrix, it doesn't print the attributes. I have been reading the parameters and I don't think this function is useful for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a DataFrame which has nodes and some of the attribute of each node.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, {'x': 11, 'y': 111})
G.add_node(2, {'x': 22, 'y': 222})
```

You can use `list comprehension` as follow to get specific node attributes:

```
pd.DataFrame([[i[0], i[1]['x'], i[1]['y']] for i in G.nodes(data=True)]
             , columns=['node_name', 'x', 'y']).set_index('node_name')


#           x   y
#node_name      
#1         11   111
#2         22   222
```

or if there are many attributes and you need all of them, this could be a better solution:

```
pd.DataFrame([i[1] for i in G.nodes(data=True)], index=[i[0] for i in G.nodes(data=True)])
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The last solution was exactly what I was looking for :)